# Using custom httphandler from a custom assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, config

Is it possible to register a custom httphandler in a stand alone assembly? I'm writing a control toolkit that uses httphandlers to perform AJAX and I would like to make the use of the toolkit as low friction for the web developers as possible. There will be quite a few handlers and I dont want the developer to have to register them all in the web.config.

Can they be referenced directly in the assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is possible, but it certainly strikes me as the wrong approach.

If you are developing your own toolkit then you could instead make a http handler that identifies and calls other http handlers based on whatever logic you want:

```
public class MyToolkitHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        IHttpHandler handler = Toolkit.GetHandler();
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
    }
}
```

This would mean that you only need to register the one handler in your web.config.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed - it's this upfront design I really want to get right!

Comment: @Rich If you are familiar with Asp.Net MVC then it might be of to look at the [source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the:

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
   </httpHandlers>
<system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
   </handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

Sections; just supply the fully-quantified name as the type.  You have to do this registration; otherwise, you can't use them in the app.  A handler has to be mapped to a URL or a handler factory to a file extension.

HTH.